# Content not floating right

Tags: css, css-float

I have a table element. The `table` element has a width manually set to 100%. I've been able to see that the `table` and `tbody` are 100%. However, the `tr` and `td` elements do not fill the entire space. My HTML looks like the following:

```
<table>
  <tbody style="width:100%; display:block !important; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100%; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:0px; height:45px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <span>Left</span>
        <span align="right" class="float:right;">Right</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Due to the fact that the `tr` and `td` do not stretch the full width, it appears like the floating is not working properly. This is just a simplified example. I REALLY need to use a table in this instance. For that reason, I'm really trying to figure out how to make the `tr`/`td` stretch the full width instead of finding another work around.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong (other than using a `table` :)).

Comment: _"I've been able to see that the table and tbody are 100%"_ Nope. And `class="float:right;"` isn't valid. Finally, why would you set `display:block !important;` on tbody? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rK9M8/

Comment: As an important note, all the fiddles in the answers below seem to work OK with much css cut-off from the OP's original code, by **playing with trial and error**, I've found that your problem is exactly caused by the style `display: block !important` you set for the `tbody`, I don't understand why you did such a weird thing? Of course another problem is the misuse of the keyword `class`, while it should be `style` in the `span` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Or this perhaps?

```
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <span style="position:relative;float:left;">Left</span>
      <span style="position:relative;float:right;">Right</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8u5Sv/

Answer (score 0):

On your span you want to float right, you should be using **style** instead of **class**. You should also move your tbody style to the table tag too:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Left</span>
        <span style="float:right;">Right</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GaryHarrower/yX7UP/

You should look at div's, but as you mentioned you know tables are wrong, I won't lecture you on this! :)

Hope this helps!

Example of div's if you're curious:
http://jsfiddle.net/GaryHarrower/45X4h/